# Is Maricha a yogi?

Tags: ramayana, yoga

Maricha in Ramayana becomes deer. Is it due to his power of yoga? If not, how he attains such body?

Comment: He was a Mayabi. A yogi is one who wants union with Paramatma! So it is clear that he was not a yogi!!

Comment: So the Rakshasas have been described at many places as Possessing Maya and being Kamarupis (changing form at will) - [Here](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga43/aranya_43_frame.htm), Lakshmana specifically describes Maricha as a Mayavi/ Kamarupi- 1. this Maareecha killed many of them resorting to many disguises, for he is a **guise-changer by his wish**. [3-43-6]; 2. अस्य **मायाविदो** माया मृग रूपम् इदम् कृतम् -trans is wrong. This **knower of Maya’s (knower of illusion’s/ magic)** Maya (illusory) Deer form is like the city of the Gandharvas. [3-43-7]. Hope this answers your Q :)